# Each time I turn on my Pokémon it comes up with my husbands Pokémon :(

Tags: pokemon-go

We both have ours under different emails through Google. I've tried uninstalling mine and re-installing but it still comes up his :(

Comment: Are you both using the same phone? What happens if you log out and log back in?

Comment: Are you logged into his Google account on the phone you re-installed on?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to log out of the account if you start it up without network connectivity.  A "Log out" button appears after a few seconds of trying to log in when there's no connectivity (turn off cellular data and wifi, or try Airplane mode).